# error while connecting to instance in aws cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

While launching an Ec2 instance there is an error occuring that "problem while connecting to your instance" .When I launched it first,it had worked properly.But after that I am continiously facing that issue

Comment: You need to provide more info. What instance? how do you connect? What error exactly? What did you do before it was working?

Comment: i used the general pupose instance in which free tier t2 micro configuration. while connection to the instance the error message comes up :"there was an problem connecting to your instance. we are unable to connect to your instance. Make sure that your instance's network settings are configured correctly for Ec2 instance connect" . I used the same configuration as before .